# Discrete valuation on $\mathbb{Q}(X,Y)$ such that the residue field is $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

I tried multiplicity of zeros and poles because this works for $\mathbb{Q}(X)$. I guessed that this would be the same for multivariable cases, but it looks more complicated and I don't know how to continue.
 By multiplicity of zeros for a two-variable polynomial, I mean the usual multiplicity defined using Hasse derivative.
I know the $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ works, but I want to know whether Hasse derivative also gives a solution.

Comment: Right. But I really want to know whether Hasse derivative works, because it looks more intuitive. In fact, if you delete your comment, this post is just showing an unsolved question and posting the question itself does no harm to the exam. I will delete the post if someone works it out using Hasse derivative. To make sure that this post does not do harm to the exam, I will add that "do not give me the solution using $\mathbb{Q}((t))$. Thank you!

Comment: I have a silly question. When you say "I know $\mathbb{Q}((t))$" works, what do you mean? Do you mean that there is a discrete valuation on $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ whose residue field is $\mathbb{Q}$?